# Incorrect CAGR output using python in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, finance

Apologies if this is an easy fix, but I can't figure out where my problem is - I am a relatively new programmer and have tried to find solutions elsewhere to no luck.

**The issue**:
I am trying to calculate CAGR in a Pandas Dataframe, but the resultant metric does not match the calculation output in excel and also a third party check.

**The Dataframe**: simply a listing of countries (rows. Eg 'Afghanistan', 'Albania',..), and a listing of years (cols. Eg '1913', '1914'...) with GDP in the body of the table

**The code**:

```
    df_gdp['CAGR'] = ((df_gdp['2013']/df_gdp['1913'])**(1/(100)-1)*100)
```

**The result**:

I have added in a column at the end with the excel calculated results which show the differences.  Indeed even with the first two rows (Afghanistan+Albania) the CAGR calc looks incorrect as it is clear Albania has grown more than Afghanistan

```
                1913            2013            CAGR        Excel
    country             
    Afghanistan 4,920,000,000   65,800,000,000  7.673647    2.627
    Albania     1,470,000,000   30,700,000,000  4.936023    3.086
    Algeria     22,600,000,000  479,000,000,000 4.864466    3.101
    Angola      3,230,000,000   152,000,000,000 2.208439    3.927
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in `()` in formula:

```
df_gdp['CAGR1'] = ((df_gdp['2013']/df_gdp['1913'])**(1/100)-1) * 100
print (df_gdp)
                    1913          2013      CAGR  Excel     CAGR1
Afghanistan   4920000000   65800000000  7.673647  2.627  2.627230
Albania       1470000000   30700000000  4.936023  3.086  3.085649
Algeria      22600000000  479000000000  4.864466  3.101  3.100856
Angola        3230000000  152000000000  2.208439  3.927  3.926526
```

Comment: How on earth did you do that so quickly!!! THANK YOU!!